# Python check if string contains any of a dictionary's keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the example dictionary:

```
LANGUAGE_TO_ISO = {
    "en": "en",
    "eng": "en",
    "english": "en",
    "es": "es",
    "spanish": "es",
    ...
}
```

And a given example strings:

```
book_title = "The Dark Tower - english"
book_title = "The Dark Tower - eng"
book_title = "The Dark Tower 2 - english 2nd edition"
```

Is there a Python function I'm unaware of that would permit to search if a string contains any of the dictionary keys then return the corresponding values, without having to loop in the ISO dictionary?

This way, I could extract the ISO language from the many different ways a language could have been written.

If someone knows of a less dirty way of doing this, please share :)

**UPDATE**:
As Willem mentioned, forgot to specify that "english", "eng", "spanish" etc would be separated by words. Either a dot, comma, hyphen, space, ...

Comment: You can prepare a regular expression, and the match "in bulk". Regular expressions can (it depends on how it is implemented) do this in linear time of the *string to match*, not the dictionary size.

Comment: So one could make an "annotated" fine state machine, like a lexer does.

Comment: Do we consider however only *words*, or does `'en'` matches in `'men'`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks for the reminder, forgot to mention about word separation, so "men" would not match but "en" would match indeed

Answer (score 2):

I dont't know if that's optimal way, and yet I have a loop, however it's pretty compact:

```py
def has_key_in(dictionary, string):
  return any(k in string for k in dictionary)
```

The advantage, if I'm not wrong, is that `any` stops at the first encountered `True` condition.

Now, the problem is that you don't have the corresponding value...

Comment: you can simplify as `any(k in string for k in dictionary)`

Comment: Close, but I need the corresponding value ;) Still, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the common key:

```
set(book_title.split()).intersection(set(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.keys()))
```

which you can lookup into the dictionary to get the corresponding value.

---

in response to comment from OP, including a snippet of the output on the shell:

```
In [4]: LANGUAGE_TO_ISO = { 
   ...:     "en": "en", 
   ...:     "eng": "en", 
   ...:     "english": "en", 
   ...:     "es": "es", 
   ...:     "spanish": "es", 
   ...: }                                                                                                                                                       

In [5]: book_title = "The Dark Tower - english"                                                                                                                 

In [6]: set(book_title.split()).intersection(set(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.keys()))                                                                                       
Out[6]: {'english'}
```

Comment: `set(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.keys())` => `LANGUAGE_TO_ISO`

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but when I try to print the result, I always get "set()"

Comment: Ok.. just realized that split() uses only spaces for splitting. If the separator is anything else like a dot or hyphen then it's not working..

Answer (score 1):

The less complex way of doing it would be to try to replace each word of the sentence using regular expressions and try to replace the word by another one using a replacement function, defaulting to the current word if not found:

```
LANGUAGE_TO_ISO = {
    "en": "en",
    "eng": "en",
    "english": "en",
    "es": "es",
    "spanish": "es",
}

book_title = "The Dark Tower - english"

import re

print(re.sub(r"\b(\w+)\b",lambda m : LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.get(m.group(1),m.group(1)),book_title))
```

prints:

```
The Dark Tower - en
```

Comment: Your solution is really great JF, thanks! I'm not advanced enough to know about lambda expressions yet and your solution looks like rocket science to me ;) I tried to extract only the "en" instead of making a replacement but I failed to modify your solution with that lambda hehe

Comment: my solution replaces the words as keys by the values, leaving the other words untouched. It may not be what you're looking for

Comment: Too bad, it looked interesting! I'm sure it will help other people however

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the *words* of the string to process, we can perform a match linear in the number of *characters* of the dictionary, with:

```
filter(None, map(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.get, book_title.split()))
```

This will contain a list of ISO codes for matched *words* (so we do *not* match `'en'` in the word `'men'`).

For example:

```
>>> book_title = "The Dark Tower - eng"
>>> list(filter(None, map(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.get, book_title.split())))
['en']
```

We can - if we want to - make it even more or less case sensitive (for some special cases, for example characters without a lowercase variant, this will not work) with:

```
filter(None, map(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.get, book_title.lower().split()))
```

(given the keys in the dictionary are all lowercase).

If you however want to be able to parse *substrings* (like `'en'` in `'men'`), then you may want to look for a *parser* (a parser works linear in the input as well, and acts like an *annotated* finite state machine).

Python splits words according to spaces, but dots, etc. will not separate the words. You can however split those with for example a regex, like:

```
import re

splt = re.compile('\W+')

filter(None, map(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.get, splt.split(book_title)))
```

Or based on your edit:

> Either a dot, comma, hyphen, space, ...

You can list the characters between square brackets:

```
import re

splt = re.compile('[\s.,-]+')

filter(None, map(LANGUAGE_TO_ISO.get, splt.split(book_title)))
```

Comment: Thanks for specifying about the word separation, I forgot to mention it! :) Your solution looks great, however I always get an empty array when printing the result list

Comment: Hmm... can you provide some sample input? Locally I generate a list of elements (as you can see in the answer).

Comment: Sure! The ISO array is exactly the same as my question (minus the "..."), and a title string I used for example was "The.Bourne.Identity.en"

Comment: @NaturalBornCamper: ha, the splitting into "words" is the problem. See edit.

Comment: Yeah, I just checked the "split" documentation after writing the comments and realized the same thing ;)